# Sculpt brushes behaving strangely in X direction

Tags: sculpting

It basically looks weird when I drag the brushes in one direction as opposed to the other, attaching an image as an example[image]

Comment: What does your topology look like? Is there a wireframe view?

Comment: I subdivided it a lot and it still behaved that way, in the bottom right you can see I had like 400k faces

Comment: basically it was black unless pretty zoomed in

Comment: No matter how many subdivisions you apply, the shape will be oddly deformed on a certain axis if the faces are rectangular, not square.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Like, let's say I wanna sculpt a rectangle, how should I go about it?